# JQuery each and on methods not working

Tags: jquery

The goal is simple. When hover over mydiv (gray) the child div of inner should appear. I'm trying to write code for that but the best I can come up with is showing all inner divs. Only the child inner div should appear.
Please help me with the code for this, I will appreciate it, thank you :)

https://jsfiddle.net/wyeqgfjz/#&togetherjs=6wNtokkegm

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mydiv {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var inner = $('.mydiv .inner'),
  mydiv = $('.mydiv');
inner.hide();
mydiv.each(function() {
  $(this).on('hover', function() {
    $(this).find(inner).toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `hover` event, the events you want are `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead.
However, jQuery has a [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method that combines the events for you.

Note that you don't have to use a loop, jQuery iterates internally for you.

```js
var inner = $('.mydiv .inner'),
    mydiv = $('.mydiv');
    
inner.hide();

mydiv.hover(function() {
  $(this).find(inner).toggle();
});
```

```css
.mydiv {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: using the variable `inner` will actually work in this instance: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/uqmkzykw/)

Comment: @empiric - indeed it does, jQuery does some magic to filter the collection it seems.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that either because of the initial selector. It is probably good to keep that in mind in case one encounters weird side effects

Comment: It's in the documentation for `find`, I looked it up before editing the answer. It was added in 1.6, and it does filter the passed in collection so as to work the same as a string selector.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use script for this at all. Can do it with css alone by using `:hover` pseudo selector

```css
.mydiv {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  padding: 40px;
  display:none;
}

.mydiv:hover .inner {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```